# Slow image opening python, recommendation for increased speed?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I'm doing some very basic image augmentation for training a convnet, and it is very slow. I was wondering if anyone has advice about a faster way to open, flip, and close images in python? It has about 100k images to go through and takes a couple hours.

```
print 'Example of image in train.txt: ' + image_file[0]
print 'Example of annotation in train.txt: ' + annot_file[0]
train_file.close()

for i in range(len(image_file)):
    temp_image = imread(image_file[i])
    temp_annot = imread(annot_file[i])

    temp_image_name = image_file[i][:-4] + '_augmented_lrflip.png'
    temp_annot_name = annot_file[i][:-4] + '_augmented_lrflip.png'
    imsave(temp_image_name,np.fliplr(temp_image))
    imsave(temp_annot_name,np.fliplr(temp_annot))

    image_file.append(temp_image_name)
    annot_file.append(temp_annot_name)

    temp_image_name = image_file[i][:-4] + '_augmented_lr_ud_flip.png'
    temp_annot_name = annot_file[i][:-4] + '_augmented_lr_ud_flip.png'
    imsave(temp_image_name,np.fliplr(np.flipud(temp_image)))
    imsave(temp_annot_name,np.fliplr(np.flipud(temp_annot)))

    image_file.append(temp_image_name)
    annot_file.append(temp_annot_name)

    temp_image_name = image_file[i][:-4] + '_augmented_udflip.png'
    temp_annot_name = annot_file[i][:-4] + '_augmented_udflip.png'
    imsave(temp_image_name,np.flipud(temp_image))
    imsave(temp_annot_name,np.flipud(temp_annot))

    image_file.append(temp_image_name)
    annot_file.append(temp_annot_name)

train_file_mod = open('train_augmented.txt', 'wb')
for i in range(len(image_file)):
    train_file_mod.write(image_file[i] + ' ' + annot_file[i] + '\n')

train_file_mod.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [Keras](http://keras.io/) (which is a deep learning abstraction layer on top of Theano or TensorFlow). It already has built-in a [ImageDataGenerator](http://keras.io/preprocessing/image/). You could essentially use it to generate different images (rotated, expanded, padded) from your dataset.

Comment: I used cv2.imwrite instead and it was much much faster. It seemed to fix my issue. I will look at keras for future use though.

Answer (score 0):

I would give the PIL or the Pillow package a try.

PIL documentation: http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/

Pillow documentation: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.3.x/

If you want to convert your images into numpy arrays and process them that way than here are some examples to do that:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577591-conversion-of-pil-image-and-numpy-array/